# Lingo Behaviour Initializer error

Tags: lingo, adobe-director

Unfortunately I'm still getting this error when I press play for this game.  Though the game is working after I press the script button, this error persists coming up whenever I press play in Director 12.  Do you know what the problem could be?  I don't see any periods in the script.  Thank you.

**Script Error:  Incorrect behavior initializer.  (Periods are not allowed in symbols)

[#pWordSource:, #pEndGameFrame: #next]**

The code is:

```
 on getPropertyDescriptionList me

   list = [:]

   -- the text member with the words in it

   addProp list, #pWordSource,\
 [#comment: "Word Source",\
 #format: #text,\
 #default: VOID]

 addProp list, #pEndGameFrame,\
 [#comment:"End Game Frame",\
 #format: #marker,\
 #default: #next])

   return list

 end
```

Comment: What director? As a first step, removed the bad tag: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287802

Comment: Try removing the extra `)` after `#next]`, it has no matching `(`

Comment: Hello and thank you.  I would like to offer the solution to this problem I was having.  Here is what James Newton, ACP from Adobe gave me which solved the problem:    I have made the following changes:
Replace...
           #default: VOID]
       with
           #default: ""]
Replace...
          #default: #next])
       with
           #default: #next]

Comment: This is Director 12....sorry I failed to mention.  cheers.